# Excel data gets formated with only one DataFormat using poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to write some cells in excel using poi with a cuurency formatter and some with a number formatter. It seems that the whole document uses the formatting I pass to it in the `constructData` method, to the last cell. Why is that and how can I fix it? I believe the code is self explanatory but if you need help be free to ask :)

```
private static final int TITLE_COLUMN_WIDTH = 8500;    
private static final int VALUES_COLUMN_WIDTH = 6000;
private static final float VALUES_ROW_HEIGHT_IN_POINTS = 26.25f;
private static final float HEADER_ROW_HEIGHT_IN_POINTS = 21.5f;
private static final String CURRENCY_DATA_FORMAT = "#,##0.00 \u20AC";
private static final String NUMBER_DATA_FORMAT = "#,##0";

private final String NO_STYLE_CURRENCY = "NO_STYLE";
private final String NO_STYLE_NUMBER = "NO_STYLE_NUMBER";
private final String LIGHT_GREY= "LIGHT_GREY";
private final String HEADER_BLUE = "HEADER_BLUE";

Map <String, HSSFCellStyle> styles = new HashMap<String, HSSFCellStyle>();

// there are other styles in this method that I call from buildHeader that don't seem to cause problems
private void populateStyles(Map <String, HSSFCellStyle> styles, HSSFWorkbook workbook){

    HSSFCellStyle noStyleWithCurrency = workbook.createCellStyle();
    noStyleWithCurrency.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat(CURRENCY_DATA_FORMAT));
    styles.put(NO_STYLE_CURRENCY,noStyleWithCurrency);

    HSSFCellStyle noStyleNumber = workbook.createCellStyle();
    noStyleNumber.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat(NUMBER_DATA_FORMAT));
    styles.put(NO_STYLE_NUMBER,noStyleNumber); }


private void ConstructData(HSSFWorkbook workbook,HSSFSheet sheet, List<Long> sortedProductNames, SalesGridModelBean model){

    Map<Long, String> productTypeNames = model.getProductTypeNames();
    Map<Long, SalesGridRowBean> gridRows = model.getGridRows();
    Long totalProductId = model.getTotalProductTypeId();
    List<SalesGridRowBean> sortedGridRows = sortAndMoveToList(gridRows, model.getTotalProductTypeId());

    int rowCount = 2; 


    for(SalesGridRowBean row : sortedGridRows){ 
        HSSFRow dataRow = sheet.createRow(rowCount);
        dataRow.setHeightInPoints(VALUES_ROW_HEIGHT_IN_POINTS);
        int cellCount = 0;

        HSSFCell nameCell = dataRow.createCell(cellCount);
        nameCell.setCellValue(row.getName());



        if(productTypeNames.size() == 1){
            SalesBean salesBean = row.getSalesBeanForProductType(totalProductId);

            HSSFCell revenueCell = dataRow.createCell(++cellCount);
            revenueCell.getCellStyle().cloneStyleFrom((styles.get(NO_STYLE_CURRENCY)));

            revenueCell.setCellValue(salesBean.getRevenue());

            HSSFCell quantityCell = dataRow.createCell(++cellCount);
            quantityCell.getCellStyle().cloneStyleFrom((styles.get(NO_STYLE_NUMBER)));

            quantityCell.setCellValue(salesBean.getSales());

            HSSFCell averageCell = dataRow.createCell(++cellCount);
            averageCell.getCellStyle().cloneStyleFrom((styles.get(NO_STYLE_CURRENCY)));

            averageCell.setCellValue(salesBean.getAveragePrice());
        } else {
            SalesBean salesBean = row.getSalesBeanForProductType(totalProductId);

            HSSFCell revenueCell = dataRow.createCell(++cellCount);
            revenueCell.getCellStyle().cloneStyleFrom((styles.get(NO_STYLE_CURRENCY)));

            revenueCell.setCellValue(salesBean.getRevenue());

            HSSFCell quantityCell = dataRow.createCell(++cellCount);
            quantityCell.getCellStyle().cloneStyleFrom((styles.get(NO_STYLE_NUMBER)));

            quantityCell.setCellValue(salesBean.getSales());


            for(int j = 0; j < sortedProductNames.size(); j++){
                 salesBean = row.getSalesBeanForProductType(sortedProductNames.get(j));

                HSSFCell revenueCell2 = dataRow.createCell(++cellCount);
                revenueCell2.getCellStyle().cloneStyleFrom((styles.get(NO_STYLE_CURRENCY)));

                revenueCell2.setCellValue(salesBean.getRevenue());

                HSSFCell quantityCell2 = dataRow.createCell(++cellCount);
                quantityCell2.getCellStyle().cloneStyleFrom((styles.get(NO_STYLE_NUMBER)));

                quantityCell2.setCellValue(salesBean.getSales());

                HSSFCell averageCell = dataRow.createCell(++cellCount);
        // This seems to cause the problem. The last assignment !!! 
       //If replaced with NO_STYLE_NUMBER uses that one
           averageCell.getCellStyle().cloneStyleFrom((styles.get(NO_STYLE_CURRENCY)));

                averageCell.setCellValue(salesBean.getAveragePrice());
            }
        }
        rowCount++;
        cellCount = 0;
    }       
}
```

PS: I construct the headers of the file (first 2 rows) using the HEADER_BLUE style and it gives no error. I do that in a separate method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647427/apache-poi-style-getting-applied-to-all-cells/33647943#33647943

Comment: @AlanHay Thank you it works now :)

Comment: Also it would be better to reduce the code-snippet to remove all the things that are not necessary for the question and only list the bare minimum needed to reproduce the problem. This would make it much easier for others to read and understand the problem.